# How to get updated response from server in MVC application when response is being cached locally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

We are caching a response on client server for 300 seconds. If within 300 seconds, data in server is getting updated then we want to retrieve updated response and not cached response. As I am relatively new to caching, I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Read my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731376/web-api-caching-how-to-implement-invalidation-using-a-distributed-cache/53747487#53747487

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web API Caching - How to implement Invalidation using a distributed cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731376/web-api-caching-how-to-implement-invalidation-using-a-distributed-cache)